# Can we use Universal Links with react native navigation?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, ios-universal-links

Problem:

In my project I have done the deep-linking part successfully with react navigation. Then I try to implement Universal Links for IOS too. When the link is clicked it is successfully opening the app with universal links in IOS. But the problem is it is not firing the linking object added to the Root navigation. This is how my code looks with root navigator.

```
    export default function App() {
  const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://mydomain/meeting'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        login: 'login/:data',
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      <AppStackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? I tried lot to find out a way to do this but I was unable to do so. Thank you!